# How to change setting in Google Groups without a Gmail address?

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-groups

I don't have a Gmail address (and I don't need one). I've been invited to a discussion group hosted at Google Groups. I accepted the invitation and now I can receive and send messages to the groups. However, now I would like to change the setting in order to get only one email per day, not every possible email. Unfortunately, when I try to access the group web page I'm asked to login with a Google account.

How can I access the group's web page and change the settings without having a Google account?

Comment: What the asker is saying is correct, and I am having the same problem. Someone added my name to a google group and I cannot adjust any settings. Can only unsubscribe by sending an email. Upon login I am asked for a Google account and not any other email, and even if I can login, that email account was added by the group owner and there is no password.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be thinking that a "Google account" and a "Gmail address" are the same thing. This is not true; you can [sign up with *any* email address](https://www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount). However, you cannot get away from the account requirement – for obvious security reasons.

Comment: OK, so basically in order to change the settings I need to sign up for a Google Account, right?